# How to get right page?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I use htmlunit library for scrapping [Yellowpages.com](http://www.yellowpages.com) site. I want to type search term into and click on Find button. But after that I get 2 pages: http://www.yellowpages.com/ny/sport?g=NY&q=Sport and https://dealoftheday.yellowpages.com/join?ic=deal_pop-under_signup-v-
First one is what I want, second one is popup.
I have this code:

```
public void getPage() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        page = webClient.getPage("http://www.yellowpages.com");
        HtmlTextInput searchInput = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("search-terms");
        searchInput.setText("Law");

        HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) page.getElementById("search-submit");
        page = button.click();
        System.out.println(page.getTitleText());

    }
```

This code prints:

> Deal of the Day on YP.com - Join

But I want to print first page title, which is:

> NY Sport | Sport in NY - YP.com

How to get first page?

EDIT: After adding line webClient.setPopupBlockerEnabled(true), I got a lot of warnings and after that I got exceptions. Here is a part of console output:

> Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ======== EcmaError:
>   lineNumber=[56] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError]
>   sourceName=[http://i2.ypcdn.com/webyp/javascripts/home_packaged.js?13455]
>   message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "blur" of null
>   (http://i2.ypcdn.com/webyp/javascripts/home_packaged.js?13455#56)]
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call
>   method "blur" of null
>   (http://i2.ypcdn.com/webyp/javascripts/home_packaged.js?13455#56)     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:531)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:906)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:164)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:223)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:686)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$2.run(HtmlElement.java:885)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:890)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:865)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.submit(HtmlForm.java:108)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput.doClickAction(HtmlSubmitInput.java:77)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1263)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1214)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1177)
>     at YellowPages.getPage(YellowPages.java:39)     at
>   YellowPages.main(YellowPages.java:22) Caused by:
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError:
>   Cannot call method "blur" of null
>   (http://i2.ypcdn.com/webyp/javascripts/home_packaged.js?13455#56)     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3772)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3750)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3778)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a JS error. Disable JS:

```
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

And what about?

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Add `webClient.getOptions()` if using HtmlUnit 2.11+

Comment: I already found solution, anyway thanks. You are right, webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false), is solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
webClient.setPopupBlockerEnabled(true)
```

Then you should get only one page

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think you might iterate through the WebClient's top level windows (using `WebClient.getTopLevelWindows()`), call `getEnclosedPage()`  and test if the title text of the page is the one you're looking for.